# split a string and save it in multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I want the users to be able to write down their skills as hashtags in a `text_field`. I already can store a string and split it up like (btw: a user has one account)

```
<% @user.account.hashtag.split('#').reject { |c| c.empty? }.each do |d| %>
   <p><%= d %></p>  
<% end %>
```

But that is not elegant as it's processed in the view right now and since its just one string which is displayed as an array, I cant iterate. What I want to achieve is explained [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPpigFAlLmE).

A user should write down his skills in one field, the string should be split up at every '#' symbol and stored in a field which should belong to the user, so I can do something like `url.com/user/hashtag/xyz` while xyz is the hashtag.

The video tutorial is made well, but it does not work for rails 5+ since find_by is not available anymore; also I don't want to create some new tables, because later I want to do the same with other models than `account`. Later I want to add a autocomplete function in a search field via gems like [select2](https://select2.org/). That is why it might help  to add another table for the tags? :S

thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I'll make use of [act-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). But if customisability and control is your priority, then I would create a `tags` model/table which has a `:name` attribute, and it [polymorphically-belongs_to](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) a `:taggable` record, of which this `:taggable` can be an `Account`, or any other model (that you said you are planning to implement the tags on).

Comment: act_as_taggable looks promising. ill try it out later. if it doesnt fit my needs, i think ill do it the "hard" way. thank you!

Comment: `find_by` is not available in rails 5+? That's very odd. I use it all the time.

Comment: `find_by` works just fine on rails 5, here's the doc https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Answer (score 0):

so there are lots of things in this short question.

The first thing that I would do would be to create a hashtag table

```
class CreateHashtags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :hashtags do |t|
      t.string :hashtag
      t.references :hashtagsable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This line is critical
`t.references :hashtagsable, polymorphic: true`
This will create 2 new field

```
:hashtagsable_type => :string, # This reference the model of the assiciation
:hashtagsable_id => :integer,  # This reference the id of the assiciation
```

This new model should look like

```
# app/models/hashtag.rb
class Hashtag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hashtagsable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now your user model you should add this line

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :hashtags, as: :hashtagsable # User.last.hashtags
end
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :hashtags, as: :hashtagsable # Account.last.hashtags
end
```

in your view should look like

```
<% @user.account.hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
   <p><%= hashtags.hashtag %> </p> 
<% end %>
```

I hope that this helps and set you in the right path